# Files in folders (powershell script)

Tags: powershell

I have 3 folders and need to check each folder if there are some files in

I did something like this

```
$directory = "C:\Folder1","C:\Folder2","C:\Folder3" 

$directoryInfo = Get-ChildItem $directory  | Measure-Object
$directoryInfo.count

if($directoryInfo.Count -gt '0')
{ 
    Write-host "Files in folders" -foregroundcolor RED 
} 
Else
{ 
    Write-host "No files here" -foregroundcolor Green 
}
```

I need to add `for each` command in and also need to know if there are some "files" in that folder show me that folder in RED like Write-host "Files in folder **$directory**"

but now I'm lost in this `for each` command... i know that's not so hard, but...

thanks for any help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe the individual directory names to `ForEach-Object`, then test them for descendant files one by one.

`ForEach-Object` will automatically bind each input value to `$_`:

```
$directory |ForEach-Object {
    $directoryName = Get-ItemPropertyValue -LiteralPath $_ -Name Name
    if(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_ -File){
        Write-Host "Files found in " -NoNewline
        Write-Host $directoryName -ForegroundColor Red
    } 
    else {
        Write-Host "No files found in " -NoNewline
        Write-Host $directoryName -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help Mathias, it works perfect just only one question if i have under $directory path like $directory ="C:\aaa\bbb\ccc\ddd" then in result it shows Files found in ddd . so only last "subdirectory" of aaa. Is it possible to show full path?

Comment: @Michal Yeah, just change `Write-Host $directoryName -ForegroundColor Red` to `Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Red` (you can remove `$directoryName = Get-ItemPropertyValue -LiteralPath $_ -Name Name` entirely if you don't plan on using the name alone)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified way of what you are trying to do:

```
$directory = "C:\Folder1","C:\Folder2","C:\Folder3" 

foreach($dir in $directory)
{
    if( (Get-ChildItem $dir | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0)
    {
        "Folder is empty"
    }
    Else
    {
        "Folder is not empty"
    }
}
```

`Foreach` iterates each of the folder here under the $directory and checks the file availability.
Hope it helps.